# The program compiles without errors but doesnt execute array assignment function C lang

Tags: c

The program compiles fine. I used `gcc -Wall`, and no errors were shown.

But somehow the function `storeFreqDrift` is not executed after the rest of the 
code. Any ideas why? Maybe some problem with pointers? at end of the code there is the file input (each number is in a new row). I want to return the array value from the function. Everything works fine so far, but now I'm stuck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int freqCount;
int calcFreqDrift(const char *file_name, int *result);
int storeFreqDrift(const char *file_name, int tab[freqCount]);

int main() {
    int result = 0;
    freqCount = calcFreqDrift("numbers.txt", &result);
    printf("total number of frequencies is   %d", freqCount);
    int tab[freqCount]; 
    tab[freqCount] = storeFreqDrift("numbers.txt", &tab[freqCount]);
    printf("kolumna nr 3 to %d", tab[3]);
}

int calcFreqDrift(const char *file_name, int *result) {
    FILE *file = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    int freqCount = 0;  
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("unable to open file %s", file_name);
    }
    while (fscanf(file, "%d", &i) == 1) {
        freqCount++;
        printf ("%d\n ", i);
        *result += i;
        printf("\n we are at row nr. %d sum of this number and all numbers before is: %d\n", freqCount, *result);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return freqCount; 
}

int storeFreqDrift(const char *file_name, int tab[freqCount]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < freqCount; i++) {
        tab[i] = 5 + tab[i - 1];
    }
    return tab[freqCount];
}
```

**numbers.txt**:

```
-14
+15
+9
+19
+18
+14
+14
-18
+15
+4
-18
-20
-2
+17
+16
-7
-3
+5
+1
-5
-11
-1
-6
-20
+1
+1
+4
+18
+5
-20
-10
+18
+5
-4
-5
-18
+9
+6
+1
-19
+13
+10
-22
-11
-14
-17
-10
-1
```

Comment: What happens in tab[i]=5+tab[i-1] when i==0?

Comment: it worst than 'just that'  because _storeFreqDrift_ receive `&tab[freqCount]` as second argument being in theory tab !

Comment: @Alain Merigot , it is just example to assign any value to tab to see if it is going to work

Comment: I don't entirely follow the purpose of using globals and variable references here. Why not simply make each function an encapsulated black box that takes input and returns output without relying on external state? This will likely resolve your woes and make it easy to follow your program logic.

Comment: @bruno the freqCount is just the size for the array of the tab here

Comment: @ggorlen basicly, the global variable, is to make sure the array is of the particular size that is required, not larger or smaller

Comment: @kenshin yes, this is why `&tab[freqCount]` is just **after** the last element of _tab_

Comment: `tab[freqCount]` is used in _several_ places and they _all_ point past the end of the array. For some, you may want `tab[0]` and others you may want `tab[freqCount - 1]`

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), so compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and use `gdb`

Answer (score 1):

From main() on line 10 you call calcFreqDrift() but in that function you close(file) on line 32 , then from main() on line 13 you call storeFreqDrift() with the name of file to open, but storeFreqDrift() does not open the file and does not read the file. Also in storeFreqDrift() the first line reads  for(int i=0; i

Comment: problem with editing my answer... in the body in storeFreqDrift you access tab[i-1] so you are before the first position (zero) in your array

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues, but the seg fault is caused by this line:

```
tab[freqCount] = storeFreqDrift("numbers.txt", &tab[freqCount]);
```

Notes:

- `&tab[freqCount]` is the address of memory after your array.  C is zero based, so the `tab` array occupies memory from `&tab[0]` to `&tab[freqCount - 1]`.  With `&tab[freqCount]` in the call, `storeFreqDrift` is about to go to town on the memory after the `tab` array.
- As mentioned in the comments, `tab[i - 1]` in your for loop will de-reference the memory location before the pointer `tab` when `i` is zero.  (Ironically, this is actually the only time that the pointer, `tab`, in `storeFreqDrift` actually points to any part of the array `tab` from `main` given the above note.)
- Because `int tab[freqCount];` is created on the stack at runtime with whatever the value of `freqCount` is, there is nothing the compiler can do help check the consistency of what is being fed into `storeFreqDrift` against the function declaration. A static code analysis tool would have more to say on the matter (e.g. http://splint.org/).
- Again, as `int tab[freqCount];` is created at runtime, there is no advantage to having the `storeFreqDrift` function signature declaring the tab parameter as "array of type".  It will degenerate to an int pointer.
- After your `for` loop: `return tab[freqCount];` will return whatever is in the memory at that location. However, your `for` loop will not have populated this location, rather it sets values from `tab[0]` to `tab[freqCount - 1]` (where `tab` is the pointer in the `storeFreqDrift` function and not the array `tab` from `main`).
- Finally, back in `main`, you store the return value into `tab[freqCount]`, which is the memory location after the `tab` array.

When an array is passed into a function in c, it is treated as a pointer. So it would be cleaner (and wouldn't seg fault) if you just called your function as:

```
value = storeFreqDrift("numbers.txt", tab);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function parameter from

```
int storeFreqDrift(const char *file_name, int tab[freqCount]);
```

to:

```
int storeFreqDrift(const char *file_name, int tab[]);
```